# Are there texts classified as Brahmanas that contain Taratamya of deities?

Tags: gods, brahmanas

Taratamya: Gradation, proportion, relative importance, comparative value.

The Paingirahasyabrahmana is alleged to do so:

[Does this alleged extended citation from Paingi Rahasya Brahmana invalidate "Vishnu and Narayana are the same"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51531/does-this-alleged-extended-citation-from-paingi-rahasya-brahmana-invalidate-vis)

Are there other better-preserved Brahmanas in which Taratamya of deities is described?